# Razor view in MVC dropdown for simple category field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

I cannot understand how to use the examples I see on here to make a dropdown list given my model. I am creating a page for adding a new item. The model for my page is the class that defines the item I am attempting to add, not the list for the dropdown (which the examples I am finding use). So my page model is:

@model HomeManager.Domain.InventoryItem

Where InventoryItem is

```
public  class InventoryItem

{
    public virtual  int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Added { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Item name cannot exceed 50 characters.")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Size { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual string Instructions { get; set; }
    public virtual int Count { get; set; }

    public virtual string UPC { get; set; }


    public InventoryItem()
    {
        // default non null dattetimevalues
        Added = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

The item I am ultimately going to save will have the Id of the location. All the examples I see on here have the look up (in my case Location which is a simple Id Name pair) as the model which is not going to work if the rest of my page is used for the Item.

I know this is pretty noob. I appreciate the help.

S

Answer (score 1):

Include an `IEnumerable<Location>` property on your model that has all of the possibilities for `Location`.  Then, set up your `DropDownList` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Location.LocationId, new SelectList(Model.Locations, "LocationId", "LocationName"), "Select Location...", new {id = "whatever"})
```

I don't know what you're `Location` type looks like so I simply inferred names.

See the `SelectList` [constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Ok, I get the new SelectList. I confess that the DropDownListFor documentation confuses me. What is the purpose of the third and forth parameter? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need it, it's just an easy way to show a default selected option.  You can also use the shorter constructor that takes the SelectList by itself.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I am good with the SelectList. It is the DropDownListFor constructor that is confusing me. First is TModel property. But the rest is confusing me as to which constructor this is. Sorry for being dense. Thanks for your patience.